# Merge Sort Error Does not contain definition and no extension method

Tags: c#, merge, reference, mergesort

I am trying to call the class Merge Sort from the program.cs but an error keeps showing up that the project does not contain a definnition for 'Merge Sort' and no extension method 'Merge Sort' accepting a first argument of type 'projectname.MergeSort' could be found. Below is the code that I have of the 2 classes. Can anyone help pls? Thanks

Class Merge Sort code:

```
class MergeSort
{
    static public void MergeSorting(int[] array, int left, int mid, int right)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[25];
        int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;

        left_end = (mid - 1);
        tmp_pos = left;
        num_elements = (right - left + 1);

        while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right))
        {
            if (array[left] <= array[mid])
                temp[tmp_pos++] = array[left++];
            else
                temp[tmp_pos++] = array[mid++];
        }

        while (left <= left_end)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = array[left++];

        while (mid <= right)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = array[mid++];

        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        {
            array[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }
    }

    static public void MergeSort_Recursive(int[] array, int left, int right)
    {
        int mid;

        if (right > left)
        {
            //splitting array into 2
            mid = (right + left) / 2;
            MergeSort_Recursive(array, left, mid);
            MergeSort_Recursive(array, (mid + 1), right);

            MergeSorting(array, left, (mid + 1), right);
        }
    }
}
```

Class program.cs code:

```
//array to be sorted
        int[] array = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

        //sort the array using merge sort
        MergeSort mSort = new MergeSort();
        int[] mergeSortedArray = mSort.MergeSort(array);
```

Comment: There is no `MergeSort` method in `MergeSort` class.

Comment: Use `MergeSort.MergeSorting(array ...);` Note that your methods are static, so they should be accessed via the class name, not via an instance.

Comment: @MatthewWatson it worked thanks :D